# Show that $\exists \ x\in X$ with $||x|| = 1$ such that $||x^*|| = x^*(x)$, for a fixed $x^* \in X^*$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a banach space which is reflexive. Show that $\exists \ x\in X$ with $||x|| = 1$ such that $||x^*|| = x^*(x)$, for a fixed $x^* \in X^*$.

Comment: By the way, it is not true in my favorite Banach space $X = \{0\}$.

Comment: I am trying to use the Hahn-Banach Theorem but not sure how to use it

Comment: Can you provide some details of your progress in your question?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Can you show it for non-zero X

Comment: Using Hahn-Banach theorem, for an non-zero element of $X^*$ (say $x^*)$, we can find $f \in X^{**}$ such that $f(x^*) = ||x^*||$ and $||f|| = 1$

Comment: This looks like you are already done. By reflexivity, you can represent that $f \in X^{**}$ by $x \in X$... My answer below gives a different proof.

Comment: I got it! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will provide some hints.

First, you can show (Hahn-Banach)
$$\|x^*\| = \sup_{\|x\| \le 1} x^*(x).$$
By definition of $\sup$, there is a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset X$ such that $\|x_n\|\le1$ and $x^*(x_n) \to \|x^*\|$.

Now, you should use the reflexivity of $X$...